# how to have multiple throwaway arguments

Tags: haskell, idioms

I know it's common to have functions like

```
f _ [] = Nothing
f a (x:xs) = ...
```

in Haskell it seems idiomatic that `_` is the throwaway parameter name.

What if I have lots I don't care about? E.g.

```
g _ _ [] _     = Nothing
g a _ (x:xs) b = ...
```

is what I would like to write but I don't think I can have multiple `_` in one definition.

So what should I do when I don't care about a lot of them?

Comment: What happened when you tried having multiple underscores?

Comment: @MarcTalbot I didn't know `_` was special in Haskell, I was assuming like in other programming languages `_` was just another valid identifier. I didn't try having multiple underscores before asking the question, probably it didn't enter my mind to do so, or I considered it a waste of time because "it would error anyway", or I was scared that even if it ran successfully I was screwing something else up somewhere (imagine it cloned the first argument or something). I felt more comfortable asking first, sorry.

Comment: you've nothing to be sorry for. :( check out https://wiki.haskell.org/Keywords#.5C (the entry for `_` is next under it).

Comment: @minseong Even in languages where `_` *is* just another identifier, there is (or may be) no problem. You can write `_, _, y, _ = ("w", "x", "y", "z")` in Python, for example.

Comment: @chepner in python `def f(_,_,y,_)` doesn't work, and `_, _, y, _ = ("w", "x", "y", "z")` is not really like a function definition, but anyway it just sets `_` to `'z'` because the `_` means the same thing every time, which would be a problem in haskell (because the arguments are not the same thing every time)

Comment: The point about function definitions holds, but if you don't care about the value of `_`, then it doesn't matter if `_` gets assigned `"w"`, `"x"`, or `"z"`, because you are never planning to *read* the value of `_`.

Comment: @chepner I suspect Haskell would complain if I did `f :: Int -> Bool -> String -> Int` and then `f a a v a = ...`. And similarly, Haskell's analogue of Python's tuple-decomposition assignment `(a,a,a) = ('a','b','c')` also errors. I don't really see the comparison between your Python example and my question :(

Comment: Yes, it would complain, because pattern matching isn't just assigning names to parameters. It's matching the *values* of the arguments. `f 3 True "bob" = ...` is a perfectly valid use of *refutable* patterns; a name like `a` is simply a an *irrefutable* pattern, but the names have to be unique. I never claimed that `_` was an ordinary pattern in Haskell.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can definitely have more than one underscore in the same function. As they are not assigned to any value, it wouldn't override anything.

It is also easier to read, as you know it won't matter what the value is and you can pay attention to what actually contributes to the result. Also, If you enable all the warnings when compiling, you will actually get an error if you do not use an argument that has a name:

```
g a b = b
```

will return a `Warning: Defined but not used: 'a'`

Comment: oh I didn't know it was actually a language feature

Comment: @minseong yeah the whole point about `_` is that it's a wildcard in the pattern matching

Comment: I'd just add that you can avoid that last warning if you name the parameter starting with underscore: `_a`.

Comment: That's because you're actually assigning the value to the variable, so memory is actually allocated. With Haskell laziness you might not see the difference but you can actually use that variable in your computation, unlike for a simple underscore

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov if you try to run `f _a = _a` it will compile and work

Comment: @Lorenzo I meant that `g _a b = b` won't give you a warning (and this applies to all `-Wunused-*` warnings, not just to function parameters).

Comment: @Lorenzo "That's because you're actually assigning the value to the variable, so memory is actually allocated." I think that's incorrect, and anyway that would apply to `g a b = b` exactly the same (unless I misunderstood what you meant).

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Sorry, misread your comment, you're totally right.